# Drag an element from an overflow:hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag an element from a container which is an overflow:hidden div. While dragging , the element goes behind the container (looks as if it's behind the screen).The draggable elements should be dragged outside of their container and remain visible once they are outside.

[**LINK TO THE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/skyrbe/D8CxT/)

Please note that

1)I cannot use the `appendTo` inside the draggable(Because it'll cause me issues elsewhere)

2)I cannot use `helper:clone` again for the same reason.

The complete code follows.

**HTML**

```
<div id='outer_container'>
    <div id = 'inner_container'>
        <div class = 'draggable_element'></div>
        <div class = 'draggable_element'></div>
        <div class = 'draggable_element'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer_container
{
    background:#ededed;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:40px;
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#inner_container
{
    position:absolute;
    width:2000px;
    height:100px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#ededed;
}

.draggable_element
{
    position:relative;
    width:90px;
    height:80px;
    top:10px;
    left:20px;
    margin-right:50px;
    background:#ff9600;
    float:left;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.draggable_element').draggable();
```

I am hoping that somebody can point me in the right direction.Thanks!

Comment: "(Because it'll cause me issues elsewhere)"... which are those issues. Maybe anything we suggest "causes you issues elswhere" too...

Comment: @Alvaro : hmm, it's a pretty complex thing and it's under wraps! Also , if the suggestions from you guys 'causes me issues elsewhere' , I can try to handle it. Thanks!

Comment: I understand the situation but I'm not certain of what the problem is. My assumption is that the draggable elements should not be dragged outside their container, would this be correct?

Comment: @Rob2211 : Thanks for your interest. The draggable element **should be dragged** outside the container. Right now , I am not able to do the same :)

Comment: So, the draggable elements should be dragged outside of their container *and remain visible* once they are outside? (Sorry, it's just not explicit in the question)

Comment: @Rob2211 : Yes , exactly :) I updated my question to include your comment :)

Comment: @harsha so what's the problem with using appendTo and clone helper? Have you tried it? http://jsfiddle.net/jJmHb/

Comment: The requirement is to drag the 'element' , the clone should not be 'visible' or 'created'

Comment: @harsha you can hide original element on drag start and show it back again when drag ends. http://jsfiddle.net/2Rp4z/

Comment: If it should be dragged outside the container, maybe you could actually take it out of the container? (I mean, on start drag, use some javascript to put it elsewhere in the DOM tree.) Otherwise, I wouldn't know how to circumvent the `overflow:hidden`, which in this case does exactly what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @MrLister : Yes , overflow:hidden is exactly doing what it is supposed to do :-) The  problem with placing it elsewhere in the DOM was that it was sticking to the wrong place and not moving the way it was supposed to. All : I did a work around solution (faked it :D ) Thanks to everyone who tried to help :-)